# Await Promise in .catch()

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, rxjs

### The question

How to (correctly) await a Promise in an Rx `Observable` chain's `.catch()` method?

### The context and the "why"

I have an Angular HTTP Interceptor for authentication.
In case there are problems with the user's auth token, the server responeds a 401.

In this case, I want to call (and await) an async method, which will remove the auth token from the client.

My code:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let observable: Observable<HttpEvent<any>> = next.handle(request);
    return observable
      .catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        let statusCode = HttpStatusCodes.fetchFromHttpErrorResponse(error);
        if(statusCode != HttpStatusCodes.Unauthorized)
          return Observable.throw(error);

        // Can't await it here, because if I do so, the Observable.throw() call below won't take effect
        // So in the later .subsribe() call, the success branch will be called if I await here,
        // while the error branch should be called
        //
        /*await*/ this.eraseAuthToken();

        return Observable.throw(error);
      });
  }
}
```

### The solution

After replacing this:

```
return Observable.throw(error);
```

with this one:

```
throw error;
```

After the replacement, I could use `Promise` as return type, I could `await`, and the exection went on correctly into the error handlers of the `.subscribe()` calls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things to be aware of:

- When using `await` the parent method needs to be marked with `async` which means it's going to return a Promise. But keep in mind that it returns a Promise automatically. The returned/thrown value is used to resolve/reject the Promise.
- The `catch` operator just like all RxJS operators that accept Observables as parameters work exactly the same way with Promises.

So all you need to do is just mark the method as `async` and at the end **rethrow the error**.

This is your simplified scenario (RxJS 5.5 with pipable operators):

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';

const error = new Error(`It's broken!`);
const asyncFunction = () => new Promise(
  resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000)
);

_throw(error)
  .pipe(
    catchError(async err => {
      console.log('start');
      await asyncFunction();
      console.log('end');

      throw err;
    })
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: console.log,
    error: e => console.log("ERROR:", e)
  });
```

See live demo (in console): https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-7lfe45?file=index.ts

This prints the following output:

```
ERROR: Error: It's broken!
```

This means that it was really sent as an `error` notification and not `next`. Also notice the 1s delay between `"start"` and `"end"`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked!
The problem with my code was that I used "return Observable.throw(error)" instead of "throw error" at the end.
The former goes into the "next" handler, the latter into the "error" handler